# Creating Observable without using Observable.create

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am using RxJava in my Android app and I want to load data from the database.

In this way, I am creating a new Observable using `Observable.create()` which returns a list of `EventLog`

```
public Observable<List<EventLog>> loadEventLogs() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<EventLog>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<EventLog>> subscriber) {
            List<DBEventLog> logs = new Select().from(DBEventLog.class).execute();
            List<EventLog> eventLogs = new ArrayList<>(logs.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++) {
                eventLogs.add(new EventLog(logs.get(i)));
            }
            subscriber.onNext(eventLogs);
        }
    });
}
```

Though it works correctly, I read that using `Observable.create()` is not actually a best practice for Rx Java (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201353/passing-parameter-to-observable-create/34202222#34202222)).

So I changed this method in this way.

```
public Observable<List<EventLog>> loadEventLogs() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Func0<List<EventLog>>() {
        @Override
        public List<EventLog> call() {
            List<DBEventLog> logs = new Select().from(DBEventLog.class).execute();
            List<EventLog> eventLogs = new ArrayList<>(logs.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++) {
                eventLogs.add(new EventLog(logs.get(i)));
            }
            return eventLogs;
        }
    });
}
```

Is this a better approach using Rx Java? Why? What is actually the difference among the two methods?

Moreover, since the database load a list of elements, makes sense to emit the entire list at once? Or should I emit one item at a time?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two methods may look like similar and behave similar but `fromCallable` deals with the difficulties of backpressure for you whereas the `create` version does not. Dealing with backpressure inside an `OnSubscribe` implementation ranges from simple to outright mind-melting; however, if omitted, you may get `MissingBackpressureException`s along asynchronous boundaries (such as `observeOn`) or even on continuation boundaries (such as `concat`).

RxJava tries to offer proper backpressure support for as much factories and operators as possible, however, there are quite a few factories and operators that can't support it.

The second problem with manual `OnSubscribe` implementation is the lack of cancellation support, especially if you generate a lot of `onNext` calls. Many of these can be replaced by standard factory methods (such as `from`) or helper classes (such as `SyncOnSubscribe`) that deal with all the complexity for you.

You may find a lot of introductions and examples that (still) use `create` for two reasons.

1. It is much easier to introduce push-based datastreams by showing how the push of events work in an imperative fashion. In my opinion, such sources spend too much time with `create` proportionally instead of talking about the standard factory methods and showing how certain common tasks (such as yours) can be achieved safely.
2. Many of these examples were created the time RxJava didn't require backpressure support or even proper synchronous cancellation support or were just ported from the Rx.NET examples (which to date doesn't support backpressure and synchronous cancellation works somehow, courtesy of C# I guess.) Generating values by calling onNext was worry-free back then. However, such use does lead to buffer bloat and excessive memory usage, therefore, the Netflix team came up with a way of limiting the memory usage by requiring observers to state how many items are they willing to proceed. This became known as backpressure.

For the second question, namely if one should create a List or a sequence of values, it depends on your source. If your source supports some kind of iteration or streaming of individual data elements (such as JDBC), you can just hook onto it and emit one by one (see `SyncOnSubscribe`). If it doesn't support it or you need it in List form anyway, then keep it as it is. You can always convert between the two forms via `toList` and `flatMapIterable` if necessary.

Comment: Looking at the example provided and the backpressure problem description, is it possible to have backpressure problems when there is only 1 item emitted? The problem I see in that Observable.create() is the missing onComplete()

Comment: Yes, because some operators do emission accounting and if more are emitted than requested, they fail the sequence.

Comment: @akarnokd - As per your answer the `SyncOnSubscribe` utility can be used to handle the issues that you mentioned in cases when multiple values are emitted (i.e. multiple onNext() calls from OnSubscribe implementation). As per the documentation this is an improvement over `Observable.create()`. If possible can you point me to some examples that showcase how to correctly use `SyncOnSubscribe`?

Comment: The unit tests are a good source of examples: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/test/java/rx/observables/SyncOnSubscribeTest.java

Answer (score 2):

As it's explain in [the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202222/476690) you linked, with `Observable.create` you'll may need to violate the advanced requirements of RxJava.

For example, you'll need to implement [backpressure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure), or how to unsubscribe.

In you case, you want to emit an item, without having to deal with backpressure or subscription. So `Observable.fromCallable` is a good call. RxJava will deal with the rest.