# Handling callbacks with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to understand what is the best way to handle a particular case, using RxJava.

I need to return an `Observable` which handles the removal of an account from the Android `AccountManager`. Unfortunately, this action is asynchronous and it needs a callback to handle the result.

Because of this, I am using the `Observable.create` method, in this way:

```
return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        final Account account = getAccountIfExist();
        if (account == null) {
            subscriber.onError(new NoUserFoundException());
            return;
        }

        accountManager.removeAccount(account, future -> {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                result = future.getResult();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Remove account not successful : ", ex);
                subscriber.onError(ex);
                return;
            }

            if (result) {
                subscriber.onNext(account.name);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } else {
                subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Cannot remove the account."));
            }
        }, null);
    });
```

But, `Observable.create` has different problems dealing backpressure and cancellation, as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204802/creating-observable-without-using-observable-create)

So, the question is, how can I use `Observable.fromCallable` (or an equivalent method) for handling callbacks (in general) and also dealing with backpressure and cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use

> Observable.defer

```
return Observable.defer(() -> {
    final Account account = getAccountIfExist();
        if (account == null) {
            return Observable.error(new NoUserFoundException());
        }
 accountManager.removeAccount(account, future -> {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                result = future.getResult();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 return Observable.error(ex);
            }

            if (result) {
                Observable.just(account.name);
            } else {
                return Observable.error(new NoUserFoundException("Cannot remove the account."))
            }
        }, null);
});
```